# Retriving data from IMF api as JSON is a nested list of dictionaries in Pandas DataFrame need the time_period and obs_value

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, loops

I am using the API from the IMF. Ultimately, I am trying to get a panel of the data. The JSON file is nested withing lists where the main data is under 'Obs'. I need to be able to connect the data pulled from Obs with it's corresponding Counter Part Area ('@COUNTERPART_AREA').

So far I have data in a dataframe1 that has been relabel and index to the counter part area. Then I created another dataframe2 that has the index and obs data from the first one. I have written some code for dataframe2 to create a dictionary to then later extract the data and join it with dataframe1.

```
key = 'http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/CDIS/A.US.IIW_BP6_USD'

# Navigate to series in API-returned JSON data
list_cdis_data = (requests.get(f'{key}').json()
        ['CompactData']['DataSet']['Series'])

list_cdis_data

[{'@FREQ': 'A',
  '@REF_AREA': 'US',
  '@INDICATOR': 'IIW_BP6_USD',
  '@COUNTERPART_AREA': 'SX',
  '@UNIT_MULT': '6',
  '@TIME_FORMAT': 'P1Y',
  'Obs': [{'@TIME_PERIOD': '2011', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2012', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2013', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2014', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2015', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2016', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2017', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}]},
 {'@FREQ': 'A',
  '@REF_AREA': 'US',
  '@INDICATOR': 'IIW_BP6_USD',
  '@COUNTERPART_AREA': 'PA',
  '@UNIT_MULT': '6',
  '@TIME_FORMAT': 'P1Y',
  'Obs': [{'@TIME_PERIOD': '2009', '@OBS_VALUE': '1101'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2010', '@OBS_VALUE': '952'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2011', '@OBS_VALUE': '1135'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2012', '@OBS_VALUE': '1218'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2013', '@OBS_VALUE': '1527'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2014', '@OBS_VALUE': '2350'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2015', '@OBS_VALUE': '2592'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2016', '@OBS_VALUE': '2723'},
   {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2017', '@OBS_VALUE': '2443'}]},

dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(list_cdis_data)
```

[dataframe1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2aQ3.png)

```
SX  A   IIW_BP6_USD     US  P1Y     6   [{'@TIME_PERIOD': '2011', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}

dataframe2= pd.DataFrame(df_list_cdis_data['observation'])

SX  [{'@TIME_PERIOD': '2011', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}
```

[dataframe2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gx6K.png)

Code  I am suing to create dictionary

```py
for i, row in obs_df_data.iterrows():
    code = i
    single_obs = obs_df_data['observation'][code]
    for row in single_obs:
        print({ code : row})
```

result -

```
{'SX': {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2011', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}}
{'SX': {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2012', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}}
....
{'PA': {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2009', '@OBS_VALUE': '1101'}}
```

Instead of printing how can I create a dictionary at the end of the line.

```py
for i, row in obs_df_data.iterrows():
    code = i
    single_obs = obs_df_data['observation'][code]
    for row in single_obs:
        obs_data = ({ code : row})
```

returns the last value

```
{'NO': {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2017', '@OBS_VALUE': '26035'}}
```

the final result after doing some joins is

[final df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8MKI.png)

this was accomplish without loops, but since there many areas, years with their corresponding value this will take too long with out a loop way.

Someone that has worked with their api might encounter this challenge.I might be doing this the hard way if someone has another way to extract the data from the json file I would appreciated. Thank you so much.

**UPDATE from the solution suggested**

```
for item in list_cdis_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'observations' : item['Obs']})
    for field in other_fields:
        df[field] = item[field]
    dfs.append(df)
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
final_df
```

[final_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJSBU.png)

[final_df_sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K44Ar.png)

Any thoughts of how to solve this issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to extract the data.  Note that with Pandas, you can assign a column to a single value and it will auto-replicate across all rows.  I added '@INDICATOR' just for illustrative purposes - this lets you specify a list of any additional fields you want included in the result.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = list()

other_fields = ['@COUNTERPART_AREA', '@INDICATOR']

for item in list_cdis_data:
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(item['Obs'])
        for field in other_fields:
            df[field] = item[field]
        dfs.append(df)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error parsing list item')
        print(item)
        print(str(ex))
```

(Edited code to add an error handler in case there are list items that do not parse correctly due to structural differences which aren't included in the sample data.  This will give info about the errors and skip over those cases).

Now if you want to concatenate into a single dataframe, you can do as follows:

```
one_big_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)

one_big_df
```

This yields a single data table with all your data in it, including the added columns.

```
@OBS_VALUE  @TIME_PERIOD    @COUNTERPART_AREA   @INDICATOR
0   0   2011    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
1   0   2012    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
2   0   2013    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
3   0   2014    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
4   0   2015    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
5   0   2016    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
6   0   2017    SX  IIW_BP6_USD
0   1101    2009    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
1   952     2010    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
2   1135    2011    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
3   1218    2012    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
4   1527    2013    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
5   2350    2014    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
6   2592    2015    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
7   2723    2016    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
8   2443    2017    PA  IIW_BP6_USD
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am trying the loop you sent, but when i am creating the df "df = pd.DataFrame(item['Obs'])"  I keep getting - If using all scalar values, you must pass an index. Is there something missing?

Comment: Is it possible that in the full dataset there are structural differences in the outer list items?  This works fine for me when I create a dict from your example data.  If there are any cases where 'Obs' is structurally different from what you listed here, it wouldn't work.  Try running the sample code on list_cdis_data[0:2].  If it works there, but not on the full set, there's likely additional cases that need to be handled.

Comment: I added a try-except to the code so it will give more detailed information on error cases.

Comment: yes you are right the errors are coming from some countries that only have data for one year

Comment: Error parsing list item
{'@FREQ': 'A', '@REF_AREA': 'US', '@INDICATOR': 'IIW_BP6_USD', '@COUNTERPART_AREA': 'RE', '@UNIT_MULT': '6', '@TIME_FORMAT': 'P1Y', 'Obs': {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2009', '@OBS_VALUE': '0'}}
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: so what I have done to keep those 'Obs' is just modify the code -                              for item in list_cdis_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'observations' : item['Obs']})
    for field in other_fields:
        df[field] = item[field]
    dfs.append(df)   --- however, the last dataframe is somewhere different. I will post an update. Thank you so much though with your help.

Comment: The question actually becomes less useful the more specific corner cases you add to it.  Parsing data is a drag as a general rule since you have to handle all the exception cases with instance-specific logic, but those details are not really desirable for a question-answer forum like this.  This question is valuable insofar as it poses a generalizable problem-solution pair (in this case, how to efficiently parse a JSON structure with pandas).  You've got a framework to work from now, you should try to work out the corner cases yourself and accept the answer if it gets you past the hurdle.